# Is there a way of removing all the words in the text that are not in other text?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have a document with many reviews. I am creating a bag-of-words BW using TfidfVectorizer. What I want to do is: I only want to use words in BW that are also in other document D.

The document D is a document with positive words. I am using this positive to improve my model. What I mean is: I only want to count the words that are positive.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thank you

I created a piece of code to do that job, as fallows:
train_x is a panda data frame with Reviews.

```
pos_file = open("positive-words.txt")
neg_file = open("negative-words.txt")

#creating arrays based on the files
for ln in pos_file:
    pos_words.append(ln.strip())
for ln in neg_file:
    neg_words.append(ln.strip())

#adding all the positive and negative words together
sentiment_words.append(pos_words)
sentiment_words.append(neg_words)

pos_file.close()
neg_file.close()

#filtering all the words that are not in the sentiment array
filtered_res =[]
for r in train_x:
    keep = []
    parts = r.split()
    for p in parts:
        if p in pos_words:
            keep.append(p)
    #turning the Review array back to text again
    filtered_res.append(" ".join(keep))

train_x = filtered_res
```

Although I was able to accomplish my needs, I know that the code is not the best. Also, I was trying to find a standard function in python to do that

PS: Python has so many features that I always ask what it can do without using the amount of code that I used

Comment: Yes you can do that, if you can show some samples and demonstrate what exactly you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Hey! Thank for answering. I edit my questions adding the code I created to solve my issue. What I want is basically: remove all the unnecessary words from the Review text and keep only the one important (Positive and Negative), and then from there create my model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more optimized version (because

1. it does not do linear search p in pos_words in the loop
2. it vectorize the loop (more pythonic)
3. instead of keeping a list for each r, it has generator version

```
import re

pos_words_set = set (pos_words)

def filter (r):
    keep = []
    # use [A-Za-z] to avoid numbers
    for p in re.finditer(r"[A-Za-z0-9]+", string):
        if p in pos_words_set:
            keep.append(p)
    return " ".join(keep)

train_x = train_x.apply(lambda x : filter(x), axis=1)
```